# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type throws an out-of-range exception..?

Tags: vb.net

i have taken all date value as date in database but when i give valye 09/11/2014..its accepting but when i give value in -30/10/2014..its giving this kind of error..why..need help...

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'TODO:add data into data base
    If ComboBox1.Text <> "" Then
        Dim ab As Long
        ab = random.Next("10000", "99999")


        Dim date1 As Date = Date.ParseExact(TextBox3.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing).Date
        Dim date2 As Date = Date.ParseExact(TextBox4.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing).Date
        Dim date3 As Date = Date.ParseExact(TextBox5.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing).Date
        'Dim date3 As Date = Date.Parse(TextBox5.Text)
        Dim date4 As Date = Date.ParseExact(TextBox6.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing).Date

        If Button1.Enabled = False Then
            If TextBox11.Text <> "" And ComboBox1.Text <> "" And TextBox2.Text <> "" And TextBox3.Text <> "" And TextBox4.Text <> "" Then
                TextBox10.Text = ab
                cm.Close()
                cm.Open()
                ComboBox1.Text = Replace(ComboBox1.Text, "'", "''")
                TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "'", "''")
                TextBox7.Text = Replace(TextBox7.Text, "'", "''")
                TextBox6.Text = Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                TextBox8.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into worker(faccno,fname,faddr,famcdue,fjoindate,fdate,fattended,fproblem,fsolution,fstatus,fremark,fassign,findate,fintime,fserviceno,falert)values ('" & TextBox11.Text & "', '" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & date1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "','" & date2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "','" & date3.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "','" & ComboBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & ComboBox2.Text & "','" & ComboBox6.Text & "','" & ComboBox5.Text & "','" & date4 & "','" & TextBox8.Text & "','" & TextBox10.Text & "','" & ComboBox3.SelectedIndex & "')"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Information Insertion sucessfull", "Save")
                MessageBox.Show(ab, "your service no is")
                Button7.PerformClick()
                cm.Close()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("enter all values then try to save information", "error")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text <> "" Then
            cm.Close()
            cm.Open()
            TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "'", "''")
            TextBox7.Text = Replace(TextBox7.Text, "'", "''")
            TextBox6.Text = Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            TextBox8.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
            ComboBox4.Text = Replace(ComboBox4.Text, "'", "''") 'TODO:this code replaces single quotes to store in data base
            cmd.CommandText = "update worker set faccno= '" & TextBox11.Text & "', fname='" & ComboBox1.Text & "',faddr='" & TextBox2.Text & "',famcdue='" & date1 & "',fjoindate='" & date2 & "',fdate='" & date3 & "',fattended='" & ComboBox4.Text & "',fproblem='" & TextBox1.Text & "',fsolution=  '" & TextBox7.Text & "',fstatus='" & ComboBox2.Text & "',fremark='" & ComboBox6.Text & "',fassign= '" & ComboBox5.Text & "',findate='" & date4 & "',fintime='" & TextBox8.Text & "',fserviceno='" & TextBox10.Text & "',falert='" & ComboBox3.SelectedIndex & "' where fserviceno='" & TextBox10.Text & "'"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show(" Information Updation sucessfull", "Save")
            Button7.PerformClick()
            cm.Close()
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("enter all values then try to save information", "error")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks despite your use of `Replace`, also it will fail if someone uses different default date/time settings as you aren't specifying an explicit culture for `ToString` or `Parse`.

Answer (score 1):

Before addressing your actual problem, I note that you're using string-concatenation to form SQL statements (**DO NOT DO THIS EVER** - use typed parameters instead!)

With respect to your posted problem: There are multiple possible causes, but the most probable cause is this line here:

```
TextBox6.Text = Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

...you're converting the date to `dd/MM/yyyy` format but your SQL server might expect slash-separated dates to be in the format `MM/dd/yyyy` (the default 1033 format - blame the Americans), in which case a month component of `30` doesn't make sense, hence the failure.

If you used parameters then you wouldn't have this problem, as the actual date value (rather than a string representation of it) is passed into the database client library which can then correctly serialize it for you in a way that will always work.